# github.com/google/go-containerregistry name.Registry

Tags: go

I was using name.ParseReference("http://host:port/some1/some2/nginx:n")
and my expectation is to get registry as http://host:port/some1/some2  and repository as nginx
the above go container registry is not allowing me to modify any of the information.
Can anybody please help me how to proceed with this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/go-containerregistry/pkg/name"
)



ref, err := name.ParseReference("nexus.example.com/repository/test/nginx:t", )

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }




    //ref = &name.Tag{Repository: name.Repository{Registry: name.Registry{}}}
    fmt.Println(ref.Context().RepositoryStr())
    fmt.Println(ref.Context().RegistryStr())
    fmt.Println(ref.Context().Name())
```